# Android Google analytics long average session time

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

We are using Google analytics in our app(iOS and Android). The Android average session time(8-10mins) seems way higher compared to the iOS(Avg: 1-2 mins).
The Android data certainly isn't right. I believe they are calculated automatically. Do we have any workaround for this?

Comment: If you have a problem with the way analytics data is collected or reported, then you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).  Since you have no code to share here that could be at fault, there's not much we can do to help.